# Can I pair Samsung IconX bluetooth earbuds with Ubuntu?

Tags: bluetooth, samsung

There is no Samsung Gear software for Ubuntu. I tried pairing by taking the earbuds out of the charging case and enabling bluetooth search from Ubuntu. Ubuntu does not see the earbuds. Is it possible to connect the Samsung bluetooth earbuds to Ubuntu laptop?

Comment: Were the earbuds in pairing mode?  Was the device they last paired with have bluetooth off?

Answer (score 2):

*Note: Assuming earpods are not connected to any other device and it is free to pair with PC*

1. Place Gear IconX earpods back in its box.
2. Close it and press small round button beside charging port until you see flashing blue light and amber (*correct color, if incorrect*) light. This indicates that Gear IconX is discoverable.
3. I had installed blueman and its bluetooth dependencies (*and more*) quite some time ago. you can check with the list below, if you need to add any packages.
4. In the graphical bluetooth, look for Gear IconX and connect. Seamlessly paired in my case. (See attached Image)

Here is list of packages supporting Bluetooth on my Linux Mint 18.1

```
ii  blueberry                                         1.1.20                                       all          A configuration tool for Bluetooth
ii  blueman                                           2.0.4-1ubuntu2                               amd64        Graphical bluetooth manager
ii  bluetooth                                         5.37-0ubuntu5.1                              all          Bluetooth support
ii  bluez                                             5.37-0ubuntu5.1                              amd64        Bluetooth tools and daemons
ii  bluez-cups                                        5.37-0ubuntu5.1                              amd64        Bluetooth printer driver for CUPS
ii  bluez-tools                                       0.2.0~20140808-5                             amd64        Set of tools to manage Bluetooth devices for linux
ii  gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0:amd64                   3.18.2-1ubuntu2                              amd64        Introspection data for GnomeBluetooth
ii  gnome-bluetooth                                   3.18.2-1ubuntu2                              amd64        GNOME Bluetooth tools
ii  libbluetooth3:amd64                               5.37-0ubuntu5.1                              amd64        Library to use the BlueZ Linux Bluetooth stack
ii  libgnome-bluetooth13:amd64                        3.18.2-1ubuntu2                              amd64        GNOME Bluetooth tools - support library
ii  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth                       1:8.0-0ubuntu3.10                            amd64        Bluetooth module for PulseAudio sound server
```

[image: Bluetooth Device List After Pairing]

Comment: This helps me a lot! Thank you!